# Should a repository class using EF initialize context in the constructor only or for each methods?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Should it be like this

```
public class DataAccess
{
    MyDbContext ctx;

    public DataAccess()
    {
         ctx = new MyDbContext();
    }

    public List<entity> GetAll()
    {
         return ctx.entities.ToList();
    }
}
```

or this

```
public List<entity> GetAll()
{
    using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
    {
        return ctx.entities.ToList();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot and if there is a problem in my questions, please inform me so that I may improve it.

Comment: You should split the questions because they are two completly different things.

Comment: okay :)
I'll think of a good title for it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal lifetime of a `DbContext` depends on your requirements and may vary from case to case but in general you should prefer short-lives contexts (the second code snippet in your sample code):

> Entity Framework’s contexts are meant to be used as short-lived instances in order to provide the most optimal performance experience ...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh949853.aspx#9

> if i have a viewmodel for adding new item and another viewmodel for displaying all or filtered items (the second viewmodel's view must always reflect any changes in the collection source), should the change be communicated from viewmodel to viewmodel directly, or viewmodel to repository to the second viewmodel?

The first view model could for example add the new item to an `ObservableCollection` of the second view model that the view binds to. So it should add the new item to the database using the respository *and* also add the new entity object to the source collection of the second view model one way or another.

Comment: I appreciate you answering my second question but as mentioned above, it really is different from my first question and title, so after 90 minutes, I would post it again :)
I am still confused on how to implement EF in an MVVM WPF application